# Showing percent symbol next to the each of the values obtained from xmobar's MultiCpu <autototal>

Tags: xmobar

I'm searching the web for some documentation, or even ready made config files, as for how to show a percentage symbol next to the each of the values obtained by xmobar's MultiCpu `<autototal>`. However, it's undocumented, and I'm not sure it's even possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `-S` switch:

```
    [...]

    -- cpu activity monitor
    , Run MultiCpu       [ "--template" , "cpu: <autototal>"
                         , "-p", "2"
                         , "-c", "0"
                         , "-S", "True"
                         , "--Low"      , "50"         -- units: %
                         , "--High"     , "85"         -- units: %
                         , "--low"      , "#5FFFAF"
                         , "--normal"   , "#FFFF00"
                         , "--high"     , "#FF0000"
                         ] 10

    [...]
```